# Scheme how to remove extra message? like ;Value ;Unspecified return value in GNU Scheme

Tags: scheme

I am computer science student in university, and my professor give me assignment about Scheme..

then, i set up the scheme 9.2 version, and try to this but, i'm gonna be crazy because of this![enter image description here][1]

```
52 error> (display "hi")
hi
;Unspecified return value
```

what is that? ;Unspecified return value

i wanna just display "hi" !

i have questions, how to remove that and how call like that? error code?, check text? or... what? there is a word?

thanks to read....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are using the read-eval-print loop. This has the effect that every expression you feed it has a response. If you don't like that you can run the program instead of using the REPL.

How to run a program is not covered by the standard so you need to check the documentation for your chosen implementation.

Here is an example using Ikarus:

```
#!r6rs
(import (rnrs))

(+ 4 5)
(display "Hello, world!")
(newline)
```

I've saved it as `test.scm` and I start it like this:

```
$ ikarus --r6rs-script  test.scm
Hello, world!
$
```

Notice the result of `(+ 4 5)` is not displayed. It is dead code since the value is calculated, but then thrown away since it is not used and then continues to evaluate the next expression. Nothing is printed unless you explicit ask it to. In Ikarus REPL you'll see this:

```
> (+ 4 5)
9
> (display "Hello, world!")
Hello, world!> (newline)

>
```

It doesn't print the undefiend value `#<void>>` in the Ikarus REPL. To see it you need to `display` it:

```
(display (if #f #t))
; ==> #<void> (not printed by the REPL), but `display` will print `#<void>`
```

Comment: Thanks! i was looking for docs.... but i didn't find anythings. <br>

Then, i just set up Ikarus! it is well done! :) and... how can i write new line here? haha.. adasdsadasdas